# TableSorter repaginate after rows are hidden

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

After searching around and not finding an answer to this, here goes.

I have a table that's paginated with tablesorter, and I'm going to add some buttons at the bottom which, when clicked, will hide certain rows in the table (ie. filter it).

Is there any way to repaginate the table (ie. refresh it) after the rows have been hidden, so that the table remains paginated, but with the rows still hidden? At the moment once rows are hidden, the first page is missing rows, and the subsequent pages' rows aren't hidden.